# Show Current Page's children and its grandchildren

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am new to DNN and trying to get our menus to display current pages children, then the children of those pages.

So I have 
Programs (My top level page) On the page it prints out it's children which I want but I can figure out how to get it to print the children, children.

```
<dnn:MENU MenuStyle="nav/sub" NodeSelector="0, -1, +2" runat="server" />
```

Above is the code I am currently using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node Selection:  0,0,0  shows only the immediate children of the current page.  So, I think -- i.e. haven't tried -- that changing your -1 to 0 is what you need.